# combining density plots in ggplot2

Tags: r, ggplot2, kernel-density, density-plot

I am trying to improve a figure containing multiple density plots. I generate the figure like so:

```
library(ggplot2)
m <- matrix(data=cbind(rnorm(50, 0, 1), rnorm(50, 0, 1.2), rnorm(50, 0, 1.4), rnorm(50, 0, 1.6)), nrow=50, ncol=4)
ms <- stack(as.data.frame(m))
ggplot(ms, aes(x=values, color=ind)) + geom_density()
```

Instead of visualizing each density individually, I want to combine them together into one 'averaged' density and indicate how consistent the densities are at each point (just like the confidence bounds produced by the `stat_smooth()` function).

I have actually tried using `stat_smooth()`, but got this error:

```
Error: stat_smooth requires the following missing aesthetics: y
```

Is there a way to use `stat_smooth()` in this situation?

Thanks!

Comment: Ths question would benefit from a [reproducible example](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/5963269/how-to-make-a-great-r-reproducible-example). And exactly do you want to "indicate how consistent the densities are at each point"?

Comment: i think you'll be better off pre-computing the densities yourself outside ggplot2, and then plotting those + smooth layer. smooth and density are two different stat functions, so you can't use one as the input of the other, afaik

Comment: I'll try doing that. Thanks for the suggestion.